# Android Crash Reporting: much more crashes reported in Google Play Console than Crashlytics

Tags: android, c++, crashlytics, google-play-console, crashlytics-android

I have a problem as I have much more crashes reported in Google Play Console than in Firebase Crashlytics. Around 15% in Google Play Console versus 2% in Crashlytics.

Note that most crashes come from C++ code (NDK/JNI).

I don't know which tool gives the correct data.

How to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried upgrading the NDK version being used in your application? It looks like a problem with Older NDK on newer Google Play Services.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will try that. Do you have any link telling what you mention? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to filter the crash reports you are getting in the Google Play Console by the app installation source?

It seems that Firebase Crashlytics failed or fails to deliver crash reports for devices where the app was not installed via Google Play, as mentioned in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74079890/why-does-crashlytics-report-so-much-less-crashes-than-google-play-console) or also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74127496/i-have-more-crashes-and-anr-errors-in-the-google-play-developer-console-than-in). An alternative cause is that the crash appears before Firebase is initialized in the app.

If it turns out that the additional number of crashes comes from non-google-play installations after Firebase already started, and that those exact crashes are not reported in Firebase Crashlytics, you should notify the Firebase team providing screenshots using the [Bug Report Form](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs).