# Why does Crashlytics report so much less crashes than Google Play Console?

Tags: android, firebase, crash, crashlytics, google-play-console

I have one app published on the Google Play Store which has Firebase Crashlytics integrated. I have seen in the Google Play Console that I have many new crashes when I deselect the filter "installed from Google Play". The crashes that belong to the set of crashes "installed from Google Play" are reported okay on Firebase Crahslytics, but the ones that belong to the set "not installed from Google Play" are not being reported on Firebase Crashlytics. My question is, why if the app was not installed in Google Play the crash is shown on Google Play Console but not on Firebase Crashlytics?

Comment: In theory that shouldn't matter, Crashlytics should still be sending crashes regardless of how the app was installed. It would be interesting to see actual proof (debug logs) that a crash that happened in an app not installed from Google Play are being sent or ignored. Check this for reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#enable-debug-logging

Comment: Hey @DiaRoRo, did you find a cause or a solution for this in the meantime?