# Google Play Console reports performLaunchActivity crash on devices with unofficial installation

Tags: android, android-activity, google-play, crashlytics, google-play-console

The Google Play Console reports some crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3835)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4011)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2325)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8633)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

What I consider to be interesting is the fact that this crash **only** appeared on devices which **did not install the application using the Play Store** (according to the filter option in the Play Console). This also happens with my latest app version that I do not have published anywhere besides Google Play (5% staged rollout). Only four hours after I submitted the staged rollout, I got a crash report like above, again from an non-google-play installation.

I found another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74079890/why-does-crashlytics-report-so-much-less-crashes-than-google-play-console) that also mentions many crashes coming from non-google-play app installations, that also indicates that Firebase Crashlytics would not be able to pick up this sort of crashes that appear on my Play Console. And I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74127496/i-have-more-crashes-and-anr-errors-in-the-google-play-developer-console-than-in) that mentions the exact stacktrace I am getting, but the issue also is not reported with Firebase Crashlytics.

There is no recognizable pattern regarding the device information. I am reported crashes from Samsung, Oppo, Alcatel, Infix, and TCL. The crash only happened on >= Android 10 so far, while the app supports >= Android 5. The crash is reproducible when it appears on a device, so then I get multiple crash reports from the same device in a row.

Do you have any ideas how to further investigate this issue or what could be causing this kind of crashes?

---

build.gradle(:app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "one.two.three"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 22
        versionName "2.3.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    namespace 'one.two.three'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  //actually redundant, I have no jar libs
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: any chance your app is using anything provided ie. by these google blobs that can not be available on some devices w/o google license?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Do you have an example what such a "blob" could be? I edited my post to also show all dependencies I am using. I think there is nothing special there.

Comment: Well, Google Play Services is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I see. No, I'm not using any special Play Services stuff, and also successfully tested the app on an Amazon Fire Tablet that comes without PS. Thanks for the hint though!