# I have more crashes and ANR errors in the Google Play Developer Console than in the Firebase Crashlytics. Is that normal?

Tags: android, firebase, crash, crashlytics, anr

I have seen in the last 30 days the Crashes and ANR errors report of my app in both Firebase Crashlytics and Google Play Developer Console.

This is what I have seen:

Firebase Crashlytics: 5 Crashes/ANR in total

Google Play Developer Console: 20 Crashes/ANR in total

It should be the other way around, Firebase Crashlytics should be reporting absolutely all the crashes/ANR and Google Play Developer Console should be reporting equal or less, but never more than Firebase Crashlytics.

Why could this be happening and how could I solve it?

I found this similar post posted some months ago: [similar post][1]

Edit:

ANR and crashes that are not shown in Firebase Crashlytics but yes in the Google Play Developer Console:

**Input dispatching timed out:**

```
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:335)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:161)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7880)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:568)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1045)
```

**java.lang.RuntimeException:**

Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:

```
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3432)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3571)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:140)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:96)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2096)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:264)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7605)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

**Input dispatching timed out (MyActivity.onInit()):**

(This one was causes in MyActivity.onInit() method and I don't find the stack trace)

**Input dispatching timed out (android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce):**

```
 at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:336)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:174)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7391)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

**Native method - android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce:**

Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF }
(stack trace is not aviable in this one also)

**android.content.ActivityNotFoundException**

Comment: Are these happening early in the initialization process? What is the Crashlytics SDK version?

Comment: @Gerardo Are these happening early in the initialization process? -- What crashes, the Firebase Crashlytics ones or the Google Play Developer Console ones? What is the Crashlytics SDK version? -- I am using BoM and this is the version I am using: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.1'

Comment: The crashes that show in the Play Console but not in Crashlytics. I wonder if they could be happening before Crashlytics initializes. It could also be related to the Android version, these work only for Android 11+ devices: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/troubleshooting?platform=android#anr-requires-android-11-plus

Comment: @Gerardo I have edited my question with most of the crashes that are shown in Play Console but not in Crashlytics to let you check if they could be happening before Crashlytics initializes as you have said. As for the Android Version I have seen a variety of Android versions in the ANR errors and Crashes.

Comment: Hey @Lechius, did you try filtering the crash reports in the Google Play Console by the app installation source? I am getting the exact same crashes that you mention, but only from devices that did not install my app using Google Play. Maybe this is also related in some way to Firebase Crashlytics not sending crash reports.

Comment: Hi Lechius, did you understand why it's happening? I have the same issue in my app